# find out which button was pressed in the foreach loop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I return to the user a list of his notes, surely that there may be an indefinite number of them.
I create buttons when the text is longer than 80 characters.

By clicking on this button, I want to catch a click among other buttons and find out all the information about his parent div. How can i do this?

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.UserTodoList)
        {
            <div class="card" style="width: 32%; margin-left: 1%; margin-top:1%">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">@item.Name</h5>
                    @if (item.Body.Length > 80)
                    {
                        <p class="card-text">@item.Body.Substring(0, 80)...</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-info" id="1234">Прочитать</button>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p class="card-text">@item.Body</p>

                    }

                    <a asp-controller="ToDo" asp-action="DeleteTodos" asp-route-todoId="@item.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Удалить</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: You could use data attributes to attach the current iterated data item to the button and then in the click handler of the button as suggested you could get the entire data for that button. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.card .btn'));

function handleClick() {
    const parent = this.parentNode; // here is parent
    console.log(parent) // lets log it to console
}

buttons.forEach((button) => { button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);})
```

BTW, you should add unique class to your buttons. It will be easier to get them by `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert in this (new one to it too) but how i would do it is add that `button` some class like `ErrorClass` and then inside `script` i would do

```
$('.ErrorButton').click(function() {
    var parent = this.parent(); // With this you get parent div container
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I can have a lot of buttons, and how you wrote will work only for the first one, judging by my experience

Comment: Look at edit. This way you can have multiple buttons